# How to call another instruction from the same Anchor program (No CPI)

Tags: anchor, solana-program, rust, account, anchor-lang

Is there a way to invoke an instruction within the same program? just for the sake of code reusability, I know we can achieve this easily with CPI when invoking different programs instructions, but I am not sure how could  I build a new context when calling instructions within the same program.

For instance how can I call `common_operation()` from `instruction_a` and `instruction_b` in the following code??

```
declare_id!("kBp94FpoGXkYsidMpWTP6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zP985uT");

#[program]
pub mod example_program {
    use super::*;

    pub fn common_operation(ctx: Context<MyCommonContext>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("WORKS!!");
        Ok(())
    }    
    
    pub fn instruction_a(ctx: Context<MyContextA>) -> Result<()> {
       // How to call here common_operation() ??
       // Do some stuff ...

    }

    pub fn instruction_b(ctx: Context<MyContextB>) -> Result<()> {
       // How to call here common_operation() ??
       // Do other stuff ...
    }
        
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyCommonContext<'info> {
    #[account()]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"account1_example".as_ref()], 
        bump = account1.bump
    )]
    pub account1: Account<'info, MyAccount1>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyContextA<'info> {
    #[account()]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"account1_example".as_ref()], 
        bump = account1.bump
    )]
    pub account1: Account<'info, MyAccount1>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"account2_example".as_ref()], 
        bump = account2.bump
    )]
    pub account2: Account<'info, MyAccount2>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct MyContextB<'info> {
    #[account()]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"account1_example".as_ref()], 
        bump = account1.bump
    )]
    pub account1: Account<'info, MyAccount1>,
    #[account(
        seeds = [b"account3_example".as_ref()], 
        bump = account3.bump
    )]
    pub account3: Account<'info, MyAccount3>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Comment: does [this](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5717/anchor-cpi-within-the-same-program-without-passing-the-program/5737#5737) help?

Comment: thanks @Ademola, that was my plan B in case it could not be done.